# Submit custom div with value from multiple JQ UI autocomplete entries

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, submit, append

I have a huge autocomplete field with a list of exams.
This field prepends values to a div right below it.

I need to be able to submit all the values of this div on form submit.
And i need a way to manipulate the div's value after entry (before submitting).
Something like a small x on each line that will delete the entry

Here's my code so far:

```
$(function() {
            function log( message ) {
        $( "<p/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#exams" );
        $( "#exams" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }  

    $("#clearexamcell").click(function(){$("#examlist").val("");}); // clears the field, ignore 

    $("#examlist").focus(function(){$(this).val("");}); // clears the field, ignore 

    $("#enterdrug").click(function(){
        log ( $("#examlist").val() );
        });     

    var fullTags = ["...."];

    $( "#examlist" ).autocomplete({
        source: fullTags,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "exam: " + ui.item.label :
                "exam: " + this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

here's the HTML:

```
<form>
<div class="ui-widget" ><label for="full0">Search Exam: </label>
<br/><br/>
<input style="width:600px;height:40px;" id="examlist" name="full0">
```

a couple of buttons:

```
<input type="button" id="enterdrug" value="enter" > 
<input type="button" id="clearexamcell"  value="clear"></div>
```

and the div that gets the results:

```
<div id="exams" style="width:100%;height:auto;padding-top:30px;border-bottom-style: solid;">
</div>  
...</form>
```

So far it works as intended and produces a div like:

```
<div id="exams" style="width:100%;height:auto;padding-top:30px;border-bottom-style: solid;">
<p>selection1</p>
<p>selection2</p>
<p>selection3</p>
<p>selection4</p>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how i can manipulate this and then submit the contents of the div when the rest of the form is complete?
Thank you.

Comment: You can have a hidden input field in your form and set the content of the `exams` div to the hidden field on submit. For the manipulation part, can you post what you have so far on [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) so we can understand what exactly you are after.

Comment: will try, never used jsfiddle before  
thanx

Comment: This - [http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/MZNYr/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/MZNYr/1/) - might help you get going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using this:

```
        log( ui.item ?
            "exam: " + ui.item.label :
            "exam: " + this.value);
```

to display to the user what he is entering
and this:

```
var updatedlist = $('div.exam').text();
        $("#submitexams").val(updatedlist);
```

to update a hidden text area with id `#submitexams` with the value of the whole displayed div

they both work on click of a button

as for the manipulation of data, if user wants to edit the list,
i added this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $(function() {
 $("#clearlastexamentry").click(function(){
 $("div.exam li:first").remove();
 var updatedlist = $('div.examlist').text();
 $("#submitexams").val(updatedlist);
 }); }); });
```

which on click of another button removes the first line (last submitted exam)from both submitted and displayed list.
not exactly what i was going for but it serves my purpose for now.
hope it helps someone, if you need a demo throw a comment and ill post something similar on jsfiddle